# Setting widths of buttons in ConstraintLayout programmatically

Tags: android

I have a few buttons inside a ConstraintLayout with different widths (as below). What I would like to accomplish is that every button has the width of the widest button in this layout. As it is fairly easy to extract the maximum width of these buttons,

```
    int maximumWidth = 0;

    for (View button : allButtons) {
        if (button.getWidth> maximumWidth) {
            maximumWidth = width;
        }
```

it is not as easy to set the widths in an equally easy manner. Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

[image: Unequal widths of buttons]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the layout params of the widest button and apply to the rest.

```
 val width = widestButton.layoutParams.width

    restOfbuttons.layoutParams.width = width

Also you can try:  btnLocation.measuredWidth()
```

Comment: This will be insufficient, as each button has different constraints. Using this code will result in all buttons having the same constraints, as is not desired.